# Open specific album using Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have a requirement to open a specific album from the photos app. But, I was unable to open the app.Please find my code below.

**code:**

```
  UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"photos-redirect://\(self.dukePhotoLibrary?.albumName as! String)")!)
```

The output of the URL expression is **photos-redirect://SAMPLE.AI POD Mon, 18 Nov 2019 12:06:36**

Please correct me and give me some example code

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to open the album in your app using image picker? or do you want to open Photos app and go to specific album?

Comment: I want to open the photos app and goto specific album

Comment: I think you can't do that, and even you do that with any private api from iOS there is high possibility of rejecting the build from app store

Comment: Can you describe why it is not possible ?

Comment: here is the link of apple provided list of url scheme which doesn't include photos app it self, https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html though there are some other links we are using normally but those are not included in the apple site

Comment: @souvickcse, ok. looks like as per this documentation, we cannot open the files app and goto a specific folder also. am I correct

Comment: I haven't checked the files app, but apple is now very much skeptical about its non-public apis, it was not same as it was 2 yrs ago

Comment: How do we just open the latest item?